# overlay images on top of an existing image (web)

Tags: c#, asp.net

My goal is to display a large rectangular image in a section of a webpage that will act as a background for other, smaller images to be laid on top of.  The smaller rectangular images will be dynamically selected based upon database entries.  I was able to create a java applet that drew the larger base rectangular image and then drew the smaller images over the base image. This worked very well.

I am attempting to recreate the functionality using C# in Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010. I have found system.drawing functionally that may work, but haven’t found a web based solution yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet is to probably do this with either javascript or silverlight.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly, you want to overlay smaller images on top of another image. At the end you'll end up with one image to display. This is easy to do in C#:

```
string image1 = @"c:\image.jpg";
string image2 = @"c:\image2.jpg";

System.Drawing.Image canvas = Bitmap.FromFile( image1 );
Graphics gra = Graphics.FromImage( canvas );
Bitmap smallImg = new Bitmap(image2);
gra.DrawImage( smallImg, new Point( 70, 70 ) );
canvas.Save( @"c:\newimage.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg );
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents here... Another thing which helped me on .NET 2.0 and 3.0 was explicitly deleting the Image, Graphics and Bitmap objects after you are done, specially when you would be accessing any of the image sources (`image1`, `image2` and `smallImg` above) within the same routine.

Deleting these objects will instantly release the file locks.  I experienced that the garbage collector wouldn't necessarily clean these up for me at the desired time, even if I made a separate sub-routine for my image manipulation.